Problem in Version of gradle in build.gradle
I am doing a projectIN FLUTTER, an APP for mapping the realtime changing latitude and longitude from firebase database  into google map
error is on the gradle version
here is the build.gradle file
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.0' // Use the latest stable version of Kotlin
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.0' // Ensure this version is compatible with your project
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2' // Ensure this version is compatible with your project
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Firebase Configuration
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.1.0.0')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.1')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aaddev.my_loc"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion // Ensure flutter.minSdkVersion is defined, otherwise use a specific value like 20
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}


I updated the kotlin version to 2.0.0 but the error is
e: C:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7b98c11195bdca8224a49fc5d6002767/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-2.0.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7b98c11195bdca8224a49fc5d6002767/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-2.0.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7b98c11195bdca8224a49fc5d6002767/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-2.0.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/810712b9a5e6b19d9828bd87b672432b/transformed/jetified-firebase-analytics-ktx-22.0.1-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.firebase.firebase_analytics_ktx_granule.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/bb9f6311be59e44fb99f3c2ff4470e95/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-22.0.1-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7m 47s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            468.6s

┌─ Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                            │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update │
│ E:\realtime2\android\build.gradle:                                                                │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                           │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1   i updated kotilin to latest version that is 2.0.0 but then also same error is rising


│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin. - What is the current version you have?

Have you tried using version 1.9.24? Please respond using @AlexMamo
